# использование timeit

Tags: python, python-3.x

заинтересовался тем, как узнать время выполнения какой-либо функции или строк кода с помощью timeit именно используя этот модуль в программе, а не из командной строки

Интересует как реализовать что-то по типу

```
start timer
my_sort()
end_timer
print(end_timer - start_timer)
```

Буду благодарен какому-нибудь похожему на этот примеру или объяснению в общих чертах об timeit (Мало что понял из документации)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, вы считали время выполнения через [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time), например:

```
import time

def my_func():
    for _ in range(1000000):
        _ ** 10

start_timer = time.time()
my_func()
end_timer = time.time()
print(end_timer - start_timer)
```

И захотели тоже самое сделать, но через [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html).

Тогда вам нужно будет в [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) передать строку с кодом, а чтобы код в ней выполнился, передать сущности и указать количество повторов `number=1` (дефолтное количество повторов `1000000`):

```
from timeit import timeit

# Указываем определенную сущность
print(timeit('my_func()', globals={'my_func': my_func}, number=1))

# Все текущие глобальные сущности
print(timeit('my_func()', globals=globals(), number=1))
```